# Possible functions satisying $f^2(x) = -x$.

Tags: functions, continuity

Determine all real continuous functions $f$ such that $f^2(x) = -x$.

Comment: $f(x)=\pm \sqrt{-x}$.

Comment: But the domain of this f is only the non-positive reals

Comment: So you are expecting a __real__ number $x$ that $x^2<0$?

Comment: No, I'm expecting a function whose domain is R

Comment: Substituting $x=1$ gives that $f^2(1)=-1$ which makes nonsense as you said $f(x)\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: So by $f^2(x)$ you mean $(f(x))^2$ not $f(f(x))$?

Answer (score 4):

I belive you have misread this question. Obviuosly there is no continuous function $f: \mathbb R \to v$ such that $(f(x))(f(x))=-x$ for all, $x$ because LHS is non-negative. I think the person who asked this question wanted you to interpret the equation as $f(f(x))=-x$ for all $x$. Actually there is no continuous function satisfying this last condition:  it is obvious that $f$ is one-to-one. Since it is continuous it is strictly monotonic. But then $f\circ f$ is strictly increasing but $-x$ is decreasing so the given equation cannot hold.

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: But how did you get that f is injective?

Comment: $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $f(f(x))=f(f(y))$ so $-x=-y$ so $x=y$.

Comment: I don't get why  f֯○f should be strictly increasing.

Comment: Any continuous one-to-one function on $\mathbb R$ is strictly monotonic. If $f$ is strictly decreasing then $x<y$ implies $f(x) >f(y)$ which implies $f(f(x))<f(f(y))$, so $f\circ f$ is increasing. Of course the same is true if $f$ is strictly increasing.